# Typescript: Define array of <T> inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, strong-typing

I'm coming from a JS background, and I'm learning TS.

I want to define an object with a single field, which is an array of strings, while taking advantage of strong typing.

```
let wrapper = {
  things: ['Thing 1']
}

wrapper.things[0] = 3; // wrong
```

Now, this works (and by works I mean it results in an error) because you can't assign a number to what has been **inferred** as an array of strings. What if I didn't want to provide an initial value to `things`, though? Something like this:

```
let wrapper = {
  things<String>: []
}

wrapper.things.push(3) // wrong
wrapper.things.push('abc') // correct
```

Comment: probably `let wrapper :{things:string[]} = {
  things: []
}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have the order a little off. Try this:

```
const wrapper = {
  things: [] as string[]
};
```

or use an interface (probably more recommended) via the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a type.

```
interface Wrapper {
    things: string[];
}

const wrapper: Wrapper = { things: [] };
```

Or, if it isn't particularly reusable, inline it:

```
const wrapper: { things: string[] } = { things: [] };
```